# $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x+\alpha_i)$ series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, products

Let $I=\{1,2,...,n\}$ for any $n\in \Bbb N$. Assume that $\forall i\in I, \alpha_i\in\Bbb R$.

What is the series expansion for $$p_n(x)=\prod_{i\in I}(x+\alpha_i)$$
I've noticed that $p_n(x)=xp_{n-1}(x)+\alpha_np_{n-1}(x)$, because $p_n(x)=(x+\alpha_n)p_{n-1}(x)$. And I've expanded the first 4, and I can tell there's a pattern, but I can't pin it down. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand the full product actually:
\begin{align}
p_n(x)&=(x+\alpha_1)(x+\alpha_2)...(x+\alpha_n) \\
&= \sum_{J\subset I}x^{n-|J|}\prod_{j\in J} \alpha_j \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \beta_k x^k
\end{align}
Where the first sum is over all subsets of $I$ (including $\emptyset$ and $I$ itself). The coefficients $\beta_k$ can be written as
\begin{align}
\beta_k = \sum_{J\subset I, |J|=n-k}\prod_{j\in J} \alpha_j
\end{align}
for example:
\begin{align}
\beta_n &= 1 \\
\beta_{n-1} &= \sum_{i\in I} \alpha_i \\
\beta_{n-2} &= \sum_{i<j\in I} \alpha_i \alpha_j \\
\beta_{n-3} &= \sum_{i<j<k\in I} \alpha_i \alpha_j \alpha_k \\
&...\\
\beta_0 &= \alpha_1\alpha_2...\alpha_n
\end{align}

Is this the kind of series expansion you were looking for?

Comment: Simple. Elegant. I love it!

Comment: Your $\beta_k$s are in the wrong order.  $\beta_0$ is the degree $n$ term, not the degree $0$ term.  In general $\beta_k$ is called the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $n-k$ in the coefficients $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$.

Comment: Oh. Yes. sry about that. fixed it